# Aws ssh permission denied

Tags: amazon-ec2

I created a new instance in Mumbai region. But cannot able to login through ssh. It shows a permission denied message.The error is as follows,

The authenticity of host `35.154.229.106 (35.154.229.106)` can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is `SHA256:PmutHZBUbFxn6SswNtlqgDBUQ87Jwne7lDkufybBmSQ`.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added `35.154.229.106` (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Eleena Jose

Comment: what are the permission on your public key? They need to be 400

Comment: I gave chmod 600

Comment: Still it is the same error even if it is 400

Comment: Also, in your aws console see if the port 22 for inbound traffic is accessible by your ip. Set it to your ip and try.

Comment: It is already given. Only newly created instance have this problem.Other instance in the same region doesn't have any issue.

Comment: Can you try with ssh -v and post the output?

Comment: The output shows like this,

Comment: debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic